# Unable to get method via Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Would love some help from experts here. I am getting the following error :

[image]

The following is my code:

```
public void MainMenu_Gold(WebDriver driver, String browser, String method ,String Xpath, String Amount, String TFA, String Code, String Cancel, String OK) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException{

    Class[] arg = new Class[12];
    arg[0] = WebDriver.class;
    arg[1] = String.class;      
    arg[2] = String.class;  
    arg[3] = String.class;
    arg[4] = String.class;
    arg[5] = String.class;  
    arg[6] = String.class;  
    arg[7] = String.class;    
    arg[8] = String.class;
    arg[9] = String.class;
    arg[10] = String.class;
    arg[11] = String.class;
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(browser); 
    Object obj = cls.newInstance(); 
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav_collapse']/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Reload Now")).click();
    points_before_Str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span[1]")).getText(); // get the points detail before reload    
    Convert_Points_Str_Dou(points_before_Str);//call the method to convert String to Double
    Points_Before = points_before_String;
    balance_before_Str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span[2]")).getText(); //get the monetary value before reload
    Convert_Balance_Str_Dou(balance_before_Str);    
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xpath)).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[@alt='Hong Leong Connect']")).click();
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='amount']")).sendKeys(Amount); //Assume minimum amount is met.     
    //Text_Not_Enough = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/p[2]")).getText();  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a")).click();//click on Next after key in amount
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span/a[1]")).click(); // Choose backup code option
    System.out.println("Code = " + Code);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='code']")).sendKeys(Code);//key in backup code
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/button")).click();
    //At this point, directing to payment channle 3rd party side
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(Cancel)).click(); //Click on cancel button on 3rd part payment page
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(OK)).click();//Click on OK Button to return to confirm Cancel
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    Reload_Pending = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/body/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div/h4")).getText();  
    Points_After = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/body/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span[1]")).getText();
    Balance_After = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/body/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span[2]")).getText();
    System.out.println("Before Method methos1, method = " + method);
    Method method1 = cls.getMethod(method, arg[0], arg[1], arg[2],arg[3],arg[4],arg[5],arg[6],arg[7],arg[8],arg[9],arg[10],arg[11]);        
    method1.invoke(obj, driver, browser, Xpath, Amount, TFA, Code, Cancel, OK, Points_Before, Reload_Pending, Points_After);
 }
```

The issue is at the 2nd last line of code, where the error occurs. The method in question is in another class, and what that line is trying to do is basically return to the main class (TC_PaymentChannel_FF.java) that calls this class (where the above code is in) and run the method (VerifyPaymentChannel) in that main class.

Hope to have advice.

Comment: What is the method in question? Make sure that the arguments are the same. Also, you can use `cls.getMethod(method, arg)`

Comment: You'd have to tell us what the arguments for `browser` and `method` being passed in are, and a little more about the method in question (is it visible from this code calling it - i.e. not `private`, etc.; what's its signature)?

Comment: @MiguelGarnachoVélez, The method is actually defined in the main class TC_Payment _Channel. It is defined as a String variable, and then sent to this displayed class via the argument in the MainMenu_Gold method. I have re-checked the arguements and they are the same.

Comment: @user2478398 I am not sure if this will answer your query, but here goes. The browser and method arguements seen here is actually passed from the main class known as TC_PaymentChannel. They are just some String variables, which have been assigned some values. For the method arguement, it was assigned the value of the method name to returned to from this class, called VerifyPaymentChannel. The method VerifyPaymentChannel is located in the main class, TC_PaymentChannel. And the method is public. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: It would really help if you can post the stacktrace as text and not as a cropped screenshot where the most important information is left out.

Comment: @lamchiomeng: And the method takes 12 arguments; the first being a `WebDriver` and the rest being `String`s?  According to your stack trace you are looking on the `TC_PaymentChannel_FF` class for the method, is that correct?  (This doesn't match what you've written above.)

Comment: @m0skit0 Here's the stack trace. I hope it's viewable.  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: TC_PaymentChannel_FF.VerifyPaymentChannel(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
 at Page_GoldReloadNow.MainMenu_Gold(Page_GoldReloadNow.java:135)
 at TC_PaymentChannel_FF.main(TC_PaymentChannel_FF.java:169)

Comment: You really have a method with 12 parameters?

Comment: @user2478398 Yes, you are right about taking 12 arguements. And yeap, it is indeed looking for the method in TC_Payment_Channel as that's where the method is. Would love your advice where did I go wrong.

Comment: Remove everything that is not related to the actual reflection and try `getMethod()` in isolation.

Comment: Another thing I'd try as a trouble-shooting step would be to call `getMethods()` on `TC_PaymentChannel` and print out all the ones found.  Make sure your `method` actually matches one.  If so, then print out the parameters using `getParameterTypes()` and make sure those match.

Comment: @m0skit0 As strange as it may sound, unfortunately I do have this method with 12 parameters.  This is the method that it is trying to call in TC_PaymentChannel                                                           `public void VerifyPaymentChannel(WebDriver driver, String browser, String Xpath, String Amount, String TFA, String Code, String Cancel, String OK, String Points_Before, String Reload_Pending, String Points_After)
 throws Throwable{`

Comment: @m0skit0 Does that mean removing the unrelated arguements ?

Comment: @CodeChimp Pardon my ignorance, but could you teach me how to do a print out of all the methods available in `TC_PaymentChannel` ?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to pass the arguments to obtain the method, you only need the arguments when actually calling the method.

Comment: @lamchiomeng `System.out.println("method: " + method.getName());` followed by `for(Class clazz : method.getParameterTypes()) System.out.println("\tparam: " + clazz);` or something to that effect

Comment: Codechimp and m0skit0, Appreciate the advice. I'll try it out and update you all on the result soon.